# Disk, disc, and hard

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Right now, there seems to be one canonical [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) tag, with 901 questions. There are also questions tagged [disk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk) and *shudder* [hard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard) [disk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk). Yes, that's [hard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard) **and** [disk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk). Should they all be retagged into [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive)?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, consistency is a good thing, and `hard-drive` looks to be the standard form in this case. I've retagged questions under `harddisk`, `hard-disk`, `hard`, and `hard-drive` as `hard-drive`. There are a good number under `disk` though, I wonder if a moderator can use their mass-retag powers on those questions.

`disc` seems to be used in the context of CD and DVD, not so much hard drives.

Comment: Yeah, I checked `disc` and retagged the one question about `hard-drive`.

Comment: Any progress on this?